# How to call a function before listview is displayed? (ASP.NET, c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

So i have a lisview, but before that i want to do some actions, like check if id_Item is equal to number from a list and than change background etc. Where should i write this code?
Any sample codes, please.
Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest using the `onLoad(EventArgs e)` method of your `ListView` , here's a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.onload(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sounds like you want to do that on the client side, not server side, right?

Comment: you can use item data boud event